# Crystal page number

Tags: crystal-reports

So I'm making a report that needs to be able to be faxed and have a cover sheet if needed. I've added a cover as the report header with a total page count. There's a page header that generates the [page n of m] but is prevented from showing on the report header using a "if (pageNumber=1) then true". Being that I don't want the [page n of m] to include the count for the cover sheet, decided to manually make a page n of m. When it prints on the page, the numbers are in a float format instead of int, how can I fix this.  Here's the Crystal Syntax I'm using and output.

```
numbervar n := PageNumber - 1;
numbervar m := TotalPageCount -1;
stringvar page := "Page " + toText(int(n)) + " of " + toText(int(m));
page
```

output: "Page 1.00 of 3.00"

I initially tried doing a reset page count after the report header, but that made the [totalPageCount] on the cover sheet 1 instead of 4.

thanks for the help, David K.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of ToText(int(n), just use ToText(n, 0).

You can find information on the different syntax for ToText [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v7r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.businessobjects.integration.eclipse.designer.doc/html/topic629.html)

Comment: like magic! it worked, thanks! SO won't let me mark it as answer for another 5 minutes... :/

Answer (score 2):

Any reason why you're not using the built in "reset page number after" feature- from the section expert?

Or just doing:

```
"Page " + toText(PageNumber - 1,0) + " of " + toText(TotalPageCount -1,0);
```

Comment: couldn't use the 'reset page number after' beacuse that made the total page count on the cover sheet 1 instead of what it really was.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the "reset page number after" feature - from the section expert then reset after your group changes. just to make your life e.z :*